Linux USB driver - How to set "URB Function" of usb request
I am trying to create a USB driver for Linux. In this driver I am trying to send a usb_ctrlrequest to a usb device to get some data back. When i send the request in my Linux driver I get no data back,
but the same request in Windows works fine.
This is the code I am using in my Linux USB driver:
    int rv;
    struct urb* urb;
    struct usb_ctrlrequest* dr;
    
    dr = kmalloc(sizeof(struct usb_ctrlrequest), GFP_NOIO);
    if (!dr)
        return -ENOMEM;

    dr->bRequestType = 0xC0;
    dr->bRequest = 144;
    dr->wValue = cpu_to_le16(0);
    dr->wIndex = cpu_to_le16(0x3000);
    dr->wLength = cpu_to_le16(0);
    
    urb = usb_alloc_urb(0, GFP_NOIO);   
    usb_fill_control_urb(urb, device, usb_rcvctrlpipe(device, 0x80), (unsigned char *)dr, 0, 0, usb_api_blocking_completion, NULL);

    rv = usb_submit_urb(urb, GFP_NOIO);

When looking at this request in Wireshark it looks like this:

The problem is the field URB Function has been set to URB_FUNCTION_CONTROL_TRANSFER_EX.
The same request sent under Windows looks like this, and the device responds correctly:

In Windows the URB Function is defined in _URB_HEADER and is a part of the URB Structure. I cannot find this field in the Linux URB structure.
So what I'm asking is how to send the usb request with the URB Function field set to URB_FUNCTION_VENDOR_DEVICE in a Linux device driver?
The closest other question I have found is this:
Set function in URB header to URB_FUNCTION_CLASS_INTERFACE

For starters, to get consistent results and help narrow the problem, after the kmalloc, try: memset(dr,0,sizeof(*dr));

From https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-w64-mingw32-4.8/+/refs/tags/gradle_1.2.0/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/usb.h  at line 130 URB_FUNCTION_CONTROL_TRANSFER_EX looks like it's winX only???

@CraigEstey, MinGW is a GCC for Windows, of course that code is expected to be compiled on Windows. But for the understanding of the protocol one needs to read USB specifications and other things.

Why is bRequest wrong?  Your code and the Windows screenshot say 144, but the Linux screenshot says 210.  Definitely need to straighten that out.

@DavidGrayson Oh, I must have screenshoted the wrong request where I was experimenting with different bRequest values.  I did not have any issues with the bRequest being incorrect.

OK.  Well, "URB function" is not something that actually gets sent to the device, so I'm not sure if it matters.  I usually debug these things with a hardware protocol analyzer so I can see exactly what packets the host and device are sending to each other.
